# Amending Apogee sensor open-source Python 2 code to operate on Raspberry pi 4 through USB port

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sensors

Working on a project to connect several sensors to Raspberry Pi 4 Model B and stream collected data to Google Cloud Platform for storage/reporting/analysis

I have an Apogee sq520 PAR sensor which connects through USB and is designed to operate on Windows and Mac (but not Linux) with an accompanying GUI to view the data. I've connected the sensor to the Raspberry PI through the USB port (since IO pins are out of the picture) and now need to write a program for the Pi to read it. After reaching out to the Apogee support team, they've shared with me the source-code (below). However, as I am a complete beginner I am having a hard time amending the code to be read by the Raspberry Pi. Need all the help and support I can get.

Notes:

- Code utilizes Pyserial library
- Code is written on Python 2.7 (according to website). - I am using Python 3
- When compiling the code as-is I receive a lot of syntax errors, regardless whether compiling in Python 2 or 3
- Sensor connects through 5V USB
- More info on sensor: https://www.apogeeinstruments.com/sq-520-full-spectrum-smart-quantum-sensor-usb/#product-tab-description

Code:

```
from serial import Serial

from time import sleep

import struct

 

GET_VOLT = '\x55!'

READ_CALIBRATION = '\x83!'

SET_CALIBRATION = '\x84%s%s!'

READ_SERIAL_NUM = '\x87!'

GET_LOGGING_COUNT = '\xf3!'

GET_LOGGED_ENTRY = '\xf2%s!'

ERASE_LOGGED_DATA = '\xf4!'

 

class Quantum(object):

                def __init__(self):

                                """Initializes class variables, and attempts to connect to device"""

                                self.quantum = None

                                self.offset = 0.0

                                self.multiplier = 0.0

                                self.connect_to_device()

 

                def connect_to_device(self):

                                """This function creates a Serial connection with the defined comport

                                and attempts to read the calibration values"""

                                port = 'COM1' # you'll have to check your device manager and put the actual com port here

                                self.quantum = Serial(port, 115200, timeout=0.5)

                                try:

                                                self.quantum.write(READ_CALIBRATION)

                                                multiplier = self.quantum.read(5)[1:]

                                                offset = self.quantum.read(4)

                                                self.multiplier = struct.unpack('<f', multiplier)[0]

                                                self.offset = struct.unpack('<f', offset)[0]

                                except (IOError, struct.Error), data:

                                                print data

                                                self.quantum = None

 

                def get_micromoles(self):

                                """This function converts the voltage to micromoles"""

                                voltage = self.read_voltage()

                                if voltage == 9999:

                                                # you could raise some sort of Exception here if you wanted to

                                                return

                                # this next line converts volts to micromoles

                                micromoles = (voltage - self.offset) * self.multiplier * 1000

                                if micromoles < 0:

                                                micromoles = 0

                                return micromoles

 

                def read_voltage(self):

                                """This function averages 5 readings over 1 second and returns

                                the result."""

                                if self.quantum == None:

                                                try:

                                                                self.connect_to_device()

                                                except IOError:

                                                                # you can raise some sort of exception here if you need to

                                                                return

                                # store the responses to average

                                response_list = []

                                # change to average more or less samples over the given time period

                                number_to_average = 5

                                # change to shorten or extend the time duration for each measurement

                                # be sure to leave as floating point to avoid truncation

                                number_of_seconds = 1.0

                                for i in range(number_to_average):

                                                try:

                                                                self.quantum.write(GET_VOLT)

                                                                response = self.quantum.read(5)[1:]

                                                except IOError, data:

                                                                print data

                                                                # dummy value to know something went wrong. could raise an

                                                                # exception here alternatively

                                                                return 9999

                                                else:

                                                                if not response:

                                                                                continue

                                                                # if the response is not 4 bytes long, this line will raise

                                                                # an exception

                                                                voltage = struct.unpack('<f', response)[0]

                                                                response_list.append(voltage)

                                                                sleep(number_of_seconds/number_to_average)

                                if response_list:

                                                return sum(response_list)/len(response_list)

                                return 0.0
```

Comment: You may be able to fix the basic syntax errors using the conversion tool `lib2to3` that comes with Python 3: `python -m lib2to3 -o output-dir mypy2file.py`. But please understand that migrating from Python 2 to Python 3 can be a tall order for a complete novice.

Comment: I think this question is too broad to answer in its current form. You've essentially dropped an enormous block of code in the question and said "fix this". Try to limit your question to a single, specific technical problem ("this line results in a syntax error and I don't understand why").